# How to properly use java Pattern object to match string patterns

Tags: java, regex, string, out-of-memory

I wrote a code that does several string operations including checking whether a given string matches with a certain regular expression. It ran just fine with 70,000 input but it started to give me out of memory error when I iteratively ran it for five-fold cross validation. It just might be the case that I have to assign more memory, but I have a feeling that I might have written an inefficient code, so wanted to double check if I didn't make any obvious mistake.

```
     static Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+).*");
     public static boolean someMethod(String line) {
         String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
         for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
             tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(",", "");
             tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(";", "");
             if(numberPattern.matcher(tokens[i]).find()) return true; 
          }
    return false;
}
```

and I have also many lines like below:

```
        token.matches("[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+");
```

Which way is more memory efficient? Do they look efficient enough? Any advice is appreciated!

Edited:

Sorry, I had a wrong code, which I intended to modify before posting this question but I forgot at the last minute. But the problem was I had many similar looking operations all over, aside from the fact that the example code did not make sense, I wanted to know if regexp comparison part was efficient.

Thanks for all of your comments, I'll look through and modify the code following the advice!

Comment: Each time you call `split(" ")` it creates its own Pattern which is used to split on space.

Comment: I would make sure the code runs correctly and makes sense before worrying about performance. You do all that work and ignore the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from what @alfasin has mentioned in his answer, you should avoid duplicating code; Rewrite the following:

```
{
    tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(",", "");
    tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(";", "");
}
```

Into:

```
tokens[i] = tokens[i].replaceAll(",|;", "");
```

And please just compute this before it was `.split()`, such that the operation doesn't have to be repeated within the loop:

```
String[] tokens = line.replaceAll(",|;", "").split(" ");
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

**Edit: After staring at your code for a bit I think I have a better solution, using regex ;)**

```
public static boolean someMethod(String line) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]*\\d")
             .matcher(line.replaceAll(",|;", "")).find();
}
```

<kbd>[Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tX6xS9/2)</kbd>
<kbd>[Online Code Demo](http://ideone.com/u4cNCN)</kbd>

- `\b` is a Word Boundary.
- It asserts position at the Boundary of a word (Start of line + after spacing)

Code Demo STDOUT:

> foo does not match
>   bar does not match
>   bar1 does match
>   foo baz bar bar1 lolz does match
>   password_01 does not match

Comment: Each invocation of `.replaceAll(",|;")` will create its own Pattern for `,|;` regex and Matcher which will try to find and remove this pattern from handled string.

Comment: @Pshemo !!! Check out [what I found on the source code of `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`...](http://gyazo.com/7208ce635bcd86a0fba6abd6bb18a4e0.png) Each invocation of `.replace(",", "")` also creates its `Pattern` for the regex `/,/`, except in this case we're doing it two times for `","` and `";"`, so `.replaceAll()` is still preferable over.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first at all, try a second look at your code... it will always return a "true" value ! You are not reading the 'match' variable, just putting values....

At second, String is immutable, so, each time you're splitting, you're creating another instances... why don't you try so create a pattern that makes the matches you want ignoring the commas and semicolons? I'm not sure, but I think it will take you less memory...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is inefficient indeed because you can return immediately once you've found that `match = true;` (no point to continue looping).

Further, are you sure you need to break the line into `tokens` ? why not check the regex only once ?

And last, if all comparisons checks failed, you should return `false` (last line).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of altering the text and splitting it you can put it all in the regex.

```
// the \\b means it must be the start of the String or a word
static Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z,;]*[0-9,;]*[0-9]");

// return true if the string contains 
// a number which might have letters in front
public static boolean someMethod(String line) {
     return numberPattern.matcher(line).find());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really puts it all in the regex though. See `tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(",", ""); tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace(";", "");`.

Comment: @Unihedron I meant to add them, thank you for the the correction.

Comment: No, this won't work. See case `";"`: It shouldn't match (in the original regex), but it did.

Comment: @Unihedron ok, now `";"` won't match as it has to have a digit.